# How to recursively remove the first set of parantheses in string of nested parantheses? (in Python)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, recursion

EDIT: 
Say I have a string of nested parentheses as follows: ((AB)CD(E(FG)HI((J(K))L))) (assume the parantheses are balanced and enclose dproperly
How do i recursively remove the first set of fully ENCLOSED parantheses of every subset of fully enclosed parentheses?

So in this case would be (ABCD(E(FG)HI(JK)). (AB) would become AB because (AB) is the first set of closed parentheses in a set of closed parentheses (from (AB) to K)), E is also the first element of a set of parentheses but since it doesn't have parentheses nothing is changed, and (J) is the first element in the set ((J)K) and therefore the parentheses would be removed.

This is similar to building an expression tree and so far I have parsed it into a nested list and thought I can recursively check if the first element of every nested list isinstance(type(list)) but I don't know how?

The nested list is as follows:

```
arr = [['A', 'B'], 'C', 'D', ['E', ['F', 'G'], 'H', 'I', [['J'], 'K']]]
```

Perhaps convert it into:

```
arr = [A, B, C, D, [E, [F, G], H, I, [J, K]]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the final outcome you are looking for? Because if you keep doing this you'll get a string without parentheses.... How is that useful for you?

Comment: Well..I would say that te output would look like `['A','B', 'C', 'D',['E','F','G','H','I',['J', 'K']]`. Saying that we start from `['J']`, then go out to `[['J'], 'K']` and remove the first braces, to get `['J', 'K']`, then we would switch to `['E', ['F', 'G'], 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']` remove the first again..etc

Comment: Based on the wording, I would agree with @Nf4r. I can't seem to follow the logic of how to arrive at your example output..

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be that, within each parenthesized substring, if that substring itself begins with a parenthesized substring, the parentheses should be removed from that inner substring. Basically, replacing `(({1}){2}) -> ({1}{2})`, except that instead of just removing parentheses from `({1})`, the same algorithm should be recursively applied to `({1})`. If that's the case, it needs a clearer description in the question.

Comment: Is this a trick question? You have 6 opening parentheses and only 5 closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this ugly function should do the trick:

```
def rm_parens(s):
    s2 = []
    consec_parens = 0
    inside_nested = False
    for c in s:
        if c == ')' and inside_nested:
            inside_nested = False
            consec_parens = 0
            continue
        if c == '(':
            consec_parens += 1
        else:
            consec_parens = 0
        if consec_parens == 2:
            inside_nested = True
        else:
            s2.append(c)
    s2 = ''.join(s2)
    if s2 == s:
        return s2
    return rm_parens(s2)

s = '((AB)CD(E(FG)HI((J)K))'
s = rm_parens(s)
print(s)
```

Note that this function will call itself recursively until no consecutive parentheses exist. However, in your example, ((AB)CD(E(FG)HI((J)K)), a single call is enough to produce (ABCD(E(FG)HI(JK)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce your logic to something clear enough to program.  What I'm getting from your explanations would look like the code below.  Note that I haven't dealt with edge cases: you'll need to check for None elements, hitting the end of the list, etc.

```
def simplfy(parse_list):

    # Find the first included list; 
    #   build a new list with that set of brackets removed.
    reduce_list = []
    for pos in len(parse_list):
        elem = parse_list[pos]
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            # remove brackets; construct new list
            reduce_list = parse_list[:pos]
            reduce_list.extend(elem)
            reduce_list.extend(parse_list[pos+1:]

    # Recur on each list element
    return_list = []
    for elem in parse_list
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            return_list.append(simplfy(elem))
        else:
            return_list.append(elem)

    return return_list
```